# Hola, quiero hacer ahora que el método transfer suma el dinero al balance a su respectivo numero de cuenta, como puede vincular esto?

Tags: python

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, account_number, name, balance):
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        
    def deposit(self, amount_deposit):
        self.amount_deposit = amount_deposit 
        self.balance += self.amount_deposit
        
    def withdrawal(self, amount_withdrawal):
        self.amount_withdrawal = amount_withdrawal
        self.balance -= self.amount_withdrawal
        
    def transfer(self, acc_to_transfer_to_obj, amount):
        self.acc_to_transfer_to_obj = acc_to_transfer_to_obj
        self.amount = amount 
        self.amount += balance
        

    def display(self):
        print(
            f"name of owner: {self.name}, account number: {self.account_number}, balance: {self.balance}")
```

Ejemplo usando los metodos

```
bank_account_1 = BankAccount(12345, "andre", 12500)
bank_account_1.withdrawal(500)
bank_account_1.display()
bank_account_1.deposit(1000)
bank_account_1.display()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He revisado el método transfer en tu clase BankAccount y noté que estás intentando incrementar self.amount por balance, lo cual no es correcto. El método transfer debería reducir el balance de la cuenta actual y aumentar el balance de la cuenta de destino por el amount especificado.

Aquí te muestro una versión corregida del método transfer:

```
def transfer(self, acc_to_transfer_to_obj, amount):
    if amount <= self.balance:  # Asegúrate de tener suficiente saldo
        self.balance -= amount  # Reduce el saldo de la cuenta actual
        acc_to_transfer_to_obj.balance += amount  # Aumenta el saldo de la cuenta de destino
    else:
        print("Insufficient funds")  # Imprime un mensaje si no hay suficiente saldo
```

Para usar este método, necesitas dos instancias de BankAccount, una que será la cuenta desde la que se transfiere y otra la cuenta destino. Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
# Instancia para Andre
bank_account_1 = BankAccount(12345, "Andre", 12500)
# Instancia para Maria
bank_account_2 = BankAccount(67890, "Maria", 15000)

# Andre transfiere 2000 a Maria
bank_account_1.transfer(bank_account_2, 2000)
```

Después de ejecutar transfer, el saldo de Andre se reducirá en 2000 y el saldo de Maria aumentará en 2000.

Comment: gracias ya he podio seguir